# Message in Skype Pop Up notification

Tags: skype, notifications, popups

Is there a way to turn off the option of the actual message content showing in the Skype for Business pop up notification box? I want to notification box with the name of the person sending the message but do not want the message content to show for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to turn off the option of the actual message content in the pop up?

Not from within Skype for Business. However, there is a 3rd party application called [SuperToast](https://www.modalitysystems.com/software/supertoast) that will allow you to do this:

> I grabbed a copy to try out. Here’s what its options window looks like.

[image: supertoastoptions]

You can disable "Display instant message text preview".

Source [Make 100% Sure You See the Notification – Using SuperToast](http://skype4businessinsider.com/instant-messaging/making-sure-you-see-skype-for-business-notifications-no-matter-what/)